# adding users to OS from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a project that consists of adding users to the OS and these users are in a text file. I have written this so far but it isn't working, telling me useradd isn't working properly. Can you tell me what's wrong?

The content of the file `user.txt` is:

```
charbel:password:1001:1001:Charbel Haddad:/home/charbel:/bin/bash:0:30:15:7:y
assil:p@ssw0rd:1002:1002:Assil:/home/assel:/bin/bash:0:30:10:5:n
marwan:p@ssw0rd:1003:1003:Marwan Ghantous:/home/marwan:/bin/bash:0:50:30:7:n
michel:password:1004:1004:Michel:/home/michel:/bin/bash:1:30:10:5:y
```

Script:

```
FILE="user.txt"

USERNAME=$(cut -d ":" -f 1 $FILE)
PASSWORD=$(cut -d ":" -f 2 $FILE)
USER_ID=$(cut -d ":" -f 3 $FILE)
GROUP_ID=$(cut -d ":" -f 4 $FILE)
USER_INFO=$(cut -d ":" -f 5 $FILE)
HOME_DIRECTORY=$(cut -d ":" -f 6 $FILE)
SHELL=$(cut -d " " -f 7 $FILE)
MIN=$(cut -d ":" -f 8 $FILE)
MAX=$(cut -d ":" -f 9 $FILE)
INACTIVE=$(cut -d ":" -f 10 $FILE)
WARNING=$(cut -d ":" -f 11 $FILE)

useradd -m -c "${USERNAME}" "${PASSWORD}" "${USER_ID}" "${GROUP_ID}" "${USER_INFO}" "${HOME_DIRECTORY}" "${SHELL}" "${MIN}" "${MAX}" "${INACTIVE}" "${WARNING}"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. The problem description "it isn't working" is not sufficient. Please show the actual output or error message and the expected output and/or describe what you want to happen and what happens instead. You have to read the file line-by-line. The `cut` commands will print the whole column.

Comment: There is a similar question with the same error in the code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65303035/10622916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question looks like homework/assignment, that's why I don't show a full solution here.

There is a nearly identical question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65303035/10622916.

The script in the question does not process individual lines of the input file. You need a loop that reads and processes a single line in every cycle.

The `cut` commands as used in the question will assign all values from the specified column to the variable, e.g. all usernames separated by whitespace like

```
USERNAME="charbel assil marwan michel"
```

If you would process a single line only, using multiple `cut` commands will work but is inefficient.

For examples how to process a file line-by-line and assign the input fields to individual variables, read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001. There are examples how to process fields separated by colons and what to do if the input may contain more fields than you need.